# Instagram result codes

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram allows you to share photos to the app via intent. Now you can define your own request code `startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_CODE_HERE)`

Now the problem arises when you retrieve the result codes from Instagram it only gives back 0 which is `RESULT_CANCELED`. Plus the moment you start firing your intent this result code is called regardless whether you closed Instagram or not.

Is this the only available result code? `RESULT_OK` does not get called even if you post your image because Instagram doesn't close.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've tried so far it seems that this is the only result you'll receive. If you look at the Instagram developer docs you can see that they don't even use 'startActivityForResult', but the *resultless* 'startActivity'.

https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/

Would be awesome if we would get a RESULT_OK. Would be even better if we'd receive some info about the posted object, like the ID.